# cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults')

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop

I did want to create front controll to Prestashop, I did get this error "bottom-65be1913.js:389 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'defaults')" when I tried to add DataTable to JavaScript.This is the code of the module

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"defer ></script>

<?php
Class NewmoduletaskModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontControllerCore

{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function initContent()
    {
        parent::initContent(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'nb_product'=>Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'product`'),
            'categories'=>Db::getInstance()->executeS('SELECT `id_category`,`name` FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'category_lang` WHERE `id_lang` = '.(int)$this->context->language->id),
            'shopname'=>Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_NAME'),
            'manufacturer'=>Db::getInstance()->getRow('SELECT * FROM`'._DB_PREFIX_.'manufacturer`')
        ));
        $this->setTemplate('module:newmodule/views/templates/front/task.tpl');
    }
    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();
        $this->context->controller->addJs('modules/'.$this->module->name.'/views/js/task.js');

    }
}
```

this is the code of java script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#producttable').DataTable({
        'processing':true,
        'serverSide':true,
        'ajax':{
            'url': mp_ajax + '?action=portable'
        },
        "columns":[
    {"data" :"id_product"},
    {"data":"name"}
        ]

    });
});
```

I did try to add scrpits to the PHP file and it did not change something